# Can class_alias() be undone?

Tags: php

Let's say that in a unit test I want to use `class_alias()` to substitute a fake class for one that would normally be used:

```
class_alias('MyFakeTestingClass', 'Some\Real\Class\Somewhere');
```

Is there any way to undo this operation so that `Some\Real\Class\Somewhere` can go back to being used normally afterward?  This does not work:

```
class_alias('Some\Real\Class\Somewhere', 'Some\Real\Class\Somewhere');
```

Comment: can you clone the original class?

Comment: Can't be done, not even with runkit...

Comment: Why undo it? Do you not have access to `new Some\Real\Class\Somewhere` even after creating a `class_alias`?

Comment: @Dagon: What do you mean by clone?

Comment: @PHPglue: Nope.  Doing that now gets me an instance of `MyFakeTestingClass`.

Comment: @chaos ignore me, i think i'm just typing randomly today.

Comment: @RyanVincent: Not useful.  Need the rest of the codebase to use `MyFakeTestingClass` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you go it the wrong way round? I have used `class_alias` before and still recall having access to the original class / namespace.

```
class Foo 
{
    // Foo
}

// Foo is the original class, placed first.
class_alias('Foo', 'Bar');

var_dump(new Bar, new Foo);
```

Comment: It's kind of confusing, but no, I have it correct for overriding a class out somewhere else in the codebase with a testing class.  What you can't do, in your example, is get at a pre-existing `Bar` class that's been masked by your alias.