# PHP: is it possible to remove class_alias?

Tags: php

Creating a class alias is straightforward in PHP, but is there any way to remove a previously created alias?

```
class_alias ('original', 'alias', false);
```

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905784/can-class-alias-be-undone) question. It doesn't look like there's a satisfactory answer there, though one of the comments alludes to 'No' being the answer.

Comment: It might not even be needed, but I do not understand the alias lifecycle. Where is it stored? How long will it be around? Will it affect other parts of the application? Too many questions.